# The view diabetes.views.signupuser didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

i am trying to submit the signup form using custom user model. whenever I try to submit the form it suppose to redirect to home page. but it gives error. my forms is good. problems occur both for render or redirect.

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate
from diabetes.forms import UserSignupForm


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'diabetes/home.html')

def signupuser(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account=authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password)
            login(request,account)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            pass

    else:
        form = UserSignupForm()
        return render(request,'diabetes/signupuser.html',{'form':form})
```

my urls.py

```
"""diabetes_project URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from diabetes import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
    path('signupuser/',views.signupuser,name="signupuser"),
```

]

Comment: Undent in the `return render(..)` from the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the else: pass

```
def signupuser(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=UserSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            raw_password=form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            account=authenticate(email=email,password=raw_password)
            login(request,account)
            return redirect('home')
```